# Column aggregations of JSON tables that are represented as array of array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, linq

First, I want to say that I feel like the more Linq that I know, the more I feel like a beginner. And even though it's been around for years, I still have a hard time finding recipes like this. Any links to good recipe sites are most welcome.

I'm using System.Text.Json not Newtonsoft.Json in my project.

This is data from the GA4 API if you're curious. I want to modify the JSON and add a object that has the sum of all the values of each metricValues. Basically, adding a totals row. The object "filteredTotals" is not present in the original JSON - it's what I want to calculate and add.

JSON data:

```
{
  "dimensionHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "sessionSourceMedium"
    }
  ],
  "metricHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "newUsers",
      "type": "TYPE_INTEGER"
    },
    {
      "name": "activeUsers",
      "type": "TYPE_INTEGER"
    },
    {
      "name": "sessions",
      "type": "TYPE_INTEGER"
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
      "dimensionValues": [
        {
          "value": "google / organic"
        }
      ],
      "metricValues": [
        {
          "value": "1441844"
        },
        {
          "value": "1527239"
        },
        {
          "value": "2614845"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dimensionValues": [
        {
          "value": "(direct) / (none)"
        }
      ],
      "metricValues": [
        {
          "value": "676615"
        },
        {
          "value": "680490"
        },
        {
          "value": "865201"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dimensionValues": [
        {
          "value": "google / cpc"
        }
      ],
      "metricValues": [
        {
          "value": "239104"
        },
        {
          "value": "248233"
        },
        {
          "value": "304656"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dimensionValues": [
        {
          "value": "bing / organic"
        }
      ],
      "metricValues": [
        {
          "value": "114356"
        },
        {
          "value": "127718"
        },
        {
          "value": "211394"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dimensionValues": [
        {
          "value": "yahoo / organic"
        }
      ],
      "metricValues": [
        {
          "value": "17582"
        },
        {
          "value": "18963"
        },
        {
          "value": "30481"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dimensionValues": [
        {
          "value": "linkedin.com / referral"
        }
      ],
      "metricValues": [
        {
          "value": "21882"
        },
        {
          "value": "23792"
        },
        {
          "value": "28765"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dimensionValues": [
        {
          "value": "bing / cpc"
        }
      ],
      "metricValues": [
        {
          "value": "20550"
        },
        {
          "value": "22868"
        },
        {
          "value": "26812"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dimensionValues": [
        {
          "value": "duckduckgo / organic"
        }
      ],
      "metricValues": [
        {
          "value": "14561"
        },
        {
          "value": "15105"
        },
        {
          "value": "24291"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  // the element representing a total row that I wish to calculate and add
  "filteredTotals": [
    {
      "dimensionValues": [
        {
          "value": "FILTERED_TOTAL"
        }
      ],
      "metricValues": [
        {
          "value": "2546494"
        },
        {
          "value": "2664408"
        },
        {
          "value": "4106445"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

}
```

Comment: You can deserialize the JSON into the POCO class consisting of the `filteredTotals` property. And in the object, you assign your desired value (filter/calculation) to the `filteredTotals` property.

Comment: The "calculation" is where I'm stumped. And I'm looking for pure Linq solution with no POCO class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to create a data model, you can parse to [`JsonNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode?view=net-8.0) from the [`System.Text.Json.Nodes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes?view=net-8.0) namespace, query the contents using LINQ and add the `"filteredTotals"` value as follows:

```
// Parse root to JsonObject.  If you have a JSON string you could do:
var obj = JsonNode.Parse(jsonString)!.AsObject();
// If you have a stream you could do
// var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonObject>(stream)!;

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString,
};

// Get max count for the rows[*].metricValues arrays.
var count = obj["rows"]?.AsArray().Max(o => o?["metricValues"]?.AsArray().Count) ?? 0;

// Get query for sums (without assuming the arrays are all the same size)
var sums = Enumerable.Range(0, count)
    .Select(i => 
            obj["rows"]?.AsArray()
            .Sum(o => o?["metricValues"]?.AsArray().ElementAtOrDefault(i)?["value"]?.Deserialize<Int64>(options)) ?? 0);
            
// Add filtered totals to obj by projecting query sums to required final data model
obj["filteredTotals"] = JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode(
    new [] { 
        new 
        {
            dimensionValues = new [] { new { value = "FILTERED_TOTAL" } },
            metricValues = sums.Select(i => new { value = i.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo) }),
        }
    });

var newJsonString = obj.ToString();
```

The idea here is to first get the maximum count of the `rows[*].metricValues` arrays, then generates an enumerable of sums of the `rows[*].metricValues[i]` values for values of `i` from zero to the array count.  The code then projects that enumerable to the required schema for `"filteredTotals"` and adds it to the root JSON object.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/avCDKH).

Note that my code doesn't assume that all the `rows[*].metricValues` arrays have the same size.  If they do, you could simplify a little as follows:

```
// Get count for the rows[*].metricValues arrays.
var count = obj["rows"]?.AsArray().Take(1).Max(o => o?["metricValues"]?.AsArray().Count) ?? 0;

// Get query for sums (assuming the arrays are all the same size)
var sums = Enumerable.Range(0, count)
    .Select(i => 
            obj["rows"]?.AsArray()
            .Sum(o => o?["metricValues"]?[i]?["value"]?.Deserialize<Int64>(options)) ?? 0);
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jImdUi).

In order to create the final value for `"filteredTotals"` I create an anonymous object with the necessary schema, then serialize it to a `JsonNode`.  I find this to be the easiest way to generate JSON on-the-fly, but if you have some objection you could do:

```
// Add filtered totals to obj by projecting query sums to required final data model
obj["filteredTotals"] = new JsonArray()
{
    new JsonObject()
    {
        { "dimensionValues", new JsonArray() { new JsonObject() { { "value", "FILTERED_TOTAL" } } } },
        { "metricValues", new JsonArray(sums.Select(i => new JsonObject() { { "value", i.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo) } }).ToArray())} ,
    },
};
```

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ln6YvM).

Finally, while your question required use of LINQ, sometimes traditional loops will be simpler, more expressive and more performant that complex LINQ grouping and projection operations, e.g.:

```
List<long> sums = new();            
foreach (var row in obj["rows"]?.AsArray() ?? Enumerable.Empty<JsonNode?>())
    foreach (var (item, index) in (row?["metricValues"]?.AsArray() ?? Enumerable.Empty<JsonNode?>()).Select((c, i) => (c, i)))
    {
        var value = item?["value"]?.Deserialize<Int64>(options) ?? 0;
        if (index < sums.Count)
            sums[index] += value;
        else
            sums.Add(value);
    }
```

Demo fiddle #4 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ief9Jq).